# How to group a list according to another list in which each element is a list of values?

Tags: python, list

I have two equal length lists

```
x = [1,[2],3] 
y=[[7],[8,9],[8,9]]
```

I would like to group the first list according to the second list. That is, the group should be the same for the x = 2,3 since the corresponding y lists is the same. The grouping should thus yield

```
[[1], [[2],3]]
```

What is the simplest way to achieve this?

Comment: please paste your desired output for better clarification

Comment: I have edited the representation

Comment: What will happen if the amount of element in the `x` larger than the amount of element in `y`?

Comment: Both will be of equal length

Comment: how did you decide that output is not `[[1], [2,3], [2,3]]`?

Comment: I would like to group according to the second list, basically the two lists can be thought of as a map, from the first list to the second, so the grouping is upon the values

Comment: Does the first list only contain integers?

Comment: No, it may contain other nested lists as well, I have updated a representation

Answer (score 2):

```py
x = [1,2,3]
y = [[7],[8,9],[8,9]]

output = []
values = []
for i, v in zip(x,y):
    if v in values:
        output[values.index(v)].append(i)
    else:
        output.append([i])
    values.append(v)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the simplest way to do it is using a dictionary.
You can use string representation of `y` elements as keys
and associated `x` elements as values:

```py
x = [1, [2], 3]
y = [[7], [8, 9], [8, 9]]

d = {}
for k, v in zip(y, x):
    if str(k) in d:
        d[str(k)].append(v)
    else:
        d[str(k)] = [v]

print(list(d.values()))
```

```
[[1], [[2], 3]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `:=` could do list comprehension in Python 3.8:

```
x = [1, [2], 3]
y = [[7], [8, 9], [8, 9]]


a = iter(x)
z = [[tmp for j in range(len(i)) if (tmp := next(a, None))] for i in y]
# [[1], [[2], 3], []]
output = [i for i in z if i] # remove [] in the list.
# [[1], [[2], 3]]
```